# What does not happen if we limit the duration of this sequences to 2014 samples?

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-power, signal-energy

I am confused with this multiple-choice question:

*Assuming that $x(n) = e^{-2n}u(n)$, what does not happen  if we limit the duration of this sequences to 2014 samples?*

A. The signal power leaks out into the entire frequency range

B. The energy of the obtained limited-duration signal is greater than that of the original signal $x(n)$

C. Spectral estimate is distorted

D. Spectral resolution is increased

I'm inclined to B because the summation of unlimited duration $x(n)$ would be greater than the limited one since $ x(n) > 0 $ but i don't know how to explain the other options.

Every help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A) Fourier transform of a finite sequence is periodic and infinite. The FT of $x(t)$ is is $1/(2 + j\omega)$, which decays permanently and power zeros at infinity; for $x[n]$, an approximation (see C) of this will repeat infinitely, so non-decayed power will persist. Below is for a generic (bandlimited) signal ([related](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/74734/50076)):

[image]

- B) $E = \sum_{n} |x[n]|^2$ - samples can never subtract energy, so $E_\text{long} \geq E_\text{short}$. $x[n] > 0$ isn't required.
- C) "Distorted" here means that $\mathcal{F}\{x[n]\}$ will not be an overlap-added version of shiftings of $\mathcal{F}\{x(t)\}$ (b above), since $x[n]_{0:2013}$ is a *trimmed* or "incomplete" version of $x[n]_{0:\infty}$. It also means there is *aliasing*, since $\mathcal{F}\{x(t)\}$ has infinite bandwidth (note, there's aliasing no matter what unless $n\rightarrow\infty$ *and* $f_s \rightarrow \infty$).
- D) Spectral resolution is proportional to sampling *rate* (time interval between samples), $f_s$, not total number of samples; I figure the assumption is that former is fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much! that's a good explanation to me:)

Comment: I wonder if we sample the above signal at frequencies $2\pi*k/2014$ for k=0,1,2,...,2013. Can that signal be uniquely recovered?