# Sparse signal FFT

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, dft, sparse-fourier-transform

Say I had a time domain signal $x[k]$ wich is sparse: $\log(N)^2$ nonzero samples and the fourier transform has only a very (very!) small number of high frequency components. Are there any techniques or algorithms for recovering these high frequency components in sublinear time? (something like $O(k^c\log(N)^d)$ where $k$ is a variable related the sparsity in either the frequency or the time domain).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Partial FFT](https://github.com/snudatalab/PFT)

[Sparse FFT](https://github.com/andrii619/SparseFFT)

Can also subsample the input, which will alias ([fold](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/74734/50076)) the high frequencies onto lower, then take FFT at the lower length, and then shift the result back onto higher frequencies as a post-processing step. If the lower frequencies are exactly zero, then the procedure is exact. Care is due for handling odd vs even, and dc and Nyquist bins; example below.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import fft, ifft

x = np.random.randn(128) + 1j * np.random.randn(128)
xf = fft(x)
# high freqs only
xf[:64-16] = 0
xf[64+16:] = 0
xhigh = ifft(xf)
xf = fft(xhigh)

# take fft at lower length, compensate for subsampling
xf_s = fft(xhigh[::2]) * 2  # xf short
xf_sc = np.zeros(len(x), dtype='complex128')  # xf short corrected
xf_sc[64-16:64] = xf_s[-16:]
xf_sc[64:64+16] = xf_s[:16]

# confirm they match
assert np.allclose(xf, xf_sc)
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about the partial FFT yet.