# Subsampling in frequency domain? Effect of sampling rate on spectrum?

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, sampling, dft, visualization

Given a sequence

$$
x[n] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
$$

and its subsampling (by e.g. factor of 2)

$$
x_\text{sub}[n] = [0, 2, 4, 6]
$$

are $x_\text{sub}$ and $x$ related in spectrum? That is, given $X = \texttt{DFT}(x)$, is there an operation $\text{op}$ such that $x_\text{sub} = \text{op}(X)$? Can it also be described in continuous-time, or in terms of sampling rate? A visual demonstration would be nice.

If there is such a method, are there practical applications?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question: how is this different from plain old aliasing? You down-sample without a lowpass filter and hence you get aliasing (which I guess you call "Folding in Fourier"). Unless I'm missing something here $op(X)$ is trivial: inverse DFT followed by down sampling will give you $x_{sub}[n]$ .

Comment: It's aliasing, yes, but `ifft(X)[::sub]` doesn't explain the spectral relationship as asked in question, or show something new. A skim of my answer would reveal this, under "Mathematically" and "Applications". In spirit of StackExchange you're only asked to read the question, but in a self-Q&A the author may spare cramming the Q with extended descriptions and move details to A for readability. Of course the Q should be self-contained, and I believe it is, as you said your $op$ is trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are discrete and continuous relations. First we state the result and demonstrate, then justify mathematically.

### Subsampling in time $\Leftrightarrow$ Folding in Fourier

Let's populate all before bin 8 with noise, and compare spectra with subsampling by 2:

[image]

Notice similarity between the two plots? What just happened was, we "folded" the spectrum from right onto left of Nyquist. We also divided by 2. That is, we did `xf2 == (xf[:32] + xf[-32:])/2`, where `xf=fft(x)`. What about subsampling by 4? Well, since `x[::4] == x[::2][::2]`, we just repeat the steps with the plot on right, then once more:

[image]

Left works as expected. Right does also - we don't see it as a sum because the modulus is displayed, and $|a + b| \neq |a| + |b|$. And indeed, right shows **aliasing** and loss of information: the plot on left is irrecoverable from plot on right, just as $(2 + 3j)$ and $(1 - 5j)$ aren't recoverable from their sum, $(3 - 2j)$.

In minimal code,

```py
import numpy as np; from numpy.fft import fft, ifft
x = np.random.randn(128)
x_sub = ifft(fft(x).reshape(4, -1).mean(axis=0))
assert np.allclose(x_sub, x[::4])
```

### Mathematically

In continuous time this is simply known as sampling, and greater subsampling factors are lower sampling rates. A derivation and discussion are provided in [this article](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/74734/50076). Main results:

$$
\hat f_d (\omega) = \frac{1}{s}\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} \hat f \left( \omega - \frac{2\pi}{s}i \right) \tag{1}
$$

where $f_d$ is the sampling of $f$ (via impulses); $s$ is the sampling interval/period; $\hat f$ is the Fourier transform of $f$. Discrete:

$$
X_\text{sub}[k] 
  = \frac{1}{\text{sub}} \sum_{i=0}^{\text{sub} - 1} 
    X\left[k + \frac{N}{\text{sub}}i\right]
$$

where $x_\text{sub}[n]$ is the subsampling of $x[n]$; $\text{sub}$ is the subsampling factor; $X$ is the DFT of $x$; $N$ is length of $x$.

### Visual: continuous-time

[image]

- Black vertical line at center: DC, $\omega=0$
- Red dashed lines: sampling rate, $1/s$
- Bottom row: shifted copies of $\hat f$, showing only 3. Note I shifted the sum upward for visual convenience.
- Top row: sum of bottom row, without the $1/s$ scaling

Here $f$ is a general complex function (note $\hat f$ isn't Hermitian-symmetric). We see aliasing and losses: once there's overlap, the bottom row cannot be recovered from the top. One can confirm the equivalence of discrete and continuous formulations.

This is an [interactive Desmos simulation](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/svnu4gv2o8), and it has flaws:

1. The shape of sum is inaccurate for high $1/s$, as more and more copies overlap - and, there's no $1/s$ scaling
2. The shift amount in terms of $s$ isn't accurately depicted. This is fixed in [another sim](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5zkzm4w8zj), but I found it less convenient for visualization.

### Subsampling with offset: generalization

What about `x[1::2]`? Well, that's just subsampling a shifted `x`, where we can use the Fourier shift property. We're also not restricted to `offset < subsampling_factor`, but the results may not be what we want, as `offset >= subsampling_factor` will wrap the right end of `x` onto left, since the method of shifting is circular.

### Lossless subsampling criteria; information capacity

- **Real-valued $x$**: highest non-zero DFT bin location is *less than* `len(x)//2//sub`. It can be more permissive, but not independent of the location of the spectrum.
- **Complex-valued $x$**: bandwidth is *less than or equal to* `len(x)//sub`. Note this is consistent with the real-valued case.

  - "Bandwidth" here is defined as the shortest circularly-contiguous interval that includes all non-zero DFT bins. E.g. if it's only positive bins, then it's the highest minus lowest non-zero bin location (plus 1).

Note that **aliasing != lossy**. This and implications for information capacity are described [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/84233/50076).

### Applications

- **Strided filtering**: STFT, CWT. Filters are stored in frequency domain, and we take `xf=fft(x)` once, so a convolution is just `ifft(xf * filter_f)`, which is much more compute-efficient than subsamping after `ifft`.
- **Unpadding/trimming**: if half of $x$ in time is zeros, contiguously, then we can drop the zeros by subsampling its spectrum by 2. Per duality, the generalization is **Subsampling in one domain $\Leftrightarrow$ Folding in other domain**. Note, for the trim effect, the zeros must be at center.
- **Partial `ifft`**: we can invert first half or second half of `x`, or other fractions, as described [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/81994/50076).

---

### Code

**Method:**

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import fft, ifft

def subsample_fourier(xf, sub, offset=0):
    if offset == 0:  # no need to hand-code, just for clarity & performance
        xfs = xf.reshape(sub, -1).mean(axis=0)
    else:
        w = np.arange(len(xf)//2 + 1) / len(xf)
        w = np.hstack([w, -w[1:-1][::-1]])
        e = np.exp(1j * 2*np.pi * w * offset)
        xfs = (e*xf).reshape(sub, -1).mean(axis=0)
    return xfs
```

**Limitation**: `len(x) / sub` must be integer. I've not tried other cases, but it should be doable.

**Validation:**

```py
# generate signal
N = 128
x = np.random.randn(N) + 1j*np.random.randn(N)
xf = fft(x)

# test common offset syntax --------------------------------------------------
for sub in (1, 2, 4, 8):
    for offset in range(sub):
        x_sub0 = x[offset::sub]
        x_sub1 = ifft(subsample_fourier(xf, sub, offset))
        assert np.allclose(x_sub0, x_sub1)

# test generalization --------------------------------------------------------
for sub in (1, 2, 4, 8):
    for offset in range(N):
        x_sub0 = np.roll(x, -offset)[::sub]
        x_sub1 = ifft(subsample_fourier(xf, sub, offset))
        assert np.allclose(x_sub0, x_sub1)
```