# Why does the bandwidth of a signal need to be half of the sampling rate?

Tags: fourier-transform, sampling, nyquist, bandwidth

Suppose I perform a DFT on some function with sampling rate of $\frac{1}{\Delta t}$. According to this [page](https://community.sw.siemens.com/s/article/digital-signal-processing-sampling-rates-bandwidth-spectral-lines-and-more), the bandwidth, which is the maximum frequency that can be analyzed when performed the DFT, is half of the sampling rate, i.e. $\frac{1}{2\Delta t}$. Why is this true and how can we prove this mathematically?

Comment: [Relevant visuals](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/74734/50076). This question could close as duplicate of multiple others, search "nyquist rate" or "sampling theorem".

Answer (score 4):

This is copied from another answer.  It needs editing.  Just be patient.

we can uniformly sample $x(t)$ if the sample rate, $f_\text{s} \triangleq \tfrac{1}{T} > 2B $, is sufficiently high

$$\begin{align}
x_\text{s}(t) &= x(t) \cdot T \, \mathbf{III}_T(t) \\
              &= x(t) \cdot T \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(t - nT) \\
              &= T \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) \, \delta(t - nT) \\
              &= T \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x(nT) \, \delta(t - nT) \\
              &= T \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x[n] \, \delta(t - nT) \\
\end{align}$$

it is also true that the [sampling function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb) is periodic and has a Fourier series.

$$\begin{align}
T \, \mathbf{III}_T(t) &\triangleq T \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(t - nT)  \\
            &= \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{j 2 \pi k f_\text{s} t} \\
\end{align}$$

turns out that all of the Fourier series coefficients are 1.  this means that the uniform sampled function is

$$\begin{align}
x_\text{s}(t) &= x(t) \cdot T \, \mathbf{III}_T(t) \\
              &= x(t) \cdot T \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(t - nT) \\
          &= x(t) \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{j 2 \pi k f_\text{s} t} \\
          &= \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) \, e^{j 2 \pi k f_\text{s} t} \\
\end{align}$$

accordingly, taking the continuous Fourier Transform, the spectrum of the sampled signal is

$$\begin{align}
X_\text{s}(f) & \triangleq \mathscr{F} \Big\{ x_\text{s}(t) \Big\} \\
          &= \mathscr{F} \left\{ \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) \, e^{j 2 \pi k f_\text{s} t} \right\} \\
          &= \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \mathscr{F} \Big\{ x(t) \, e^{j 2 \pi k f_\text{s} t} \Big\} \\
          &= \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}  X(f - k f_\text{s}) \\
\end{align}$$

and we know, as long as $B < \tfrac12 f_\text{s}$, that there is no overlap in the adjacent shifted spectra of $X(f)$ and the original $X(f)$ can be recovered from the $k=0$ term of the summation.

$$\begin{align}
X(f) &= \Pi\left( \tfrac{f}{f_\text{s}} \right) \, \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}  X(f - k f_\text{s}) \\
     &= \Pi\left( \tfrac{f}{f_\text{s}} \right) \, X_\text{s}(f) \\
\end{align}$$

where $\Pi(u)$ (sometimes "$\operatorname{rect}(u)$") is the [rectangular function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function)

$$\Pi(u) \triangleq \begin{cases}
1        \qquad & \text{ if } |u| < \tfrac12 \\
\tfrac12 \qquad & \text{ if } |u| = \tfrac12 \\
0        \qquad & \text{ if } |u| > \tfrac12 \\
\end{cases}$$

and we know that the inverse Fourier transform is

$$ \mathscr{F}^{-1} \left\{ \Pi\left( \tfrac{f}{f_\text{s}} \right) \right\} = f_\text{s} \, \operatorname{sinc}(f_\text{s} t) $$

where the [sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) is

$$\operatorname{sinc}(u) \triangleq \begin{cases}
\frac{\sin(\pi u)}{\pi u} \qquad & \text{ if } |u| \ne 0 \\
1        \qquad & \text{ if } |u| = 0 \\
\end{cases}$$

then, remembering that $f_\text{s}=\tfrac1T $, we know that the output of the brickwall reconstruction filter is

$$\begin{align}
X(f) &= \Pi\left( \tfrac{f}{f_\text{s}} \right) \, X_\text{s}(f) \\
 & \iff \\
x(t) &= f_\text{s} \, \operatorname{sinc}(f_\text{s} t) \ \circledast \ x_\text{s}(t) \\
     &= f_\text{s} \, \operatorname{sinc}(f_\text{s} t) \ \circledast \ T \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x(nT) \, \delta(t - nT) \\
     &= f_\text{s} \, T \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x(nT) \, \big( \operatorname{sinc}(f_\text{s} t) \ \circledast \ \delta(t - nT) \big) \\
     &=  \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x(nT) \, \operatorname{sinc}\big( f_\text{s} (t - nT) \big) \\
     &=  \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x(nT) \, \operatorname{sinc}\big( f_\text{s} t - n \big) \\
\end{align}$$

that's how we reconstruct out original $x(t)$ out of the samples $x(nT)$.  so much for the sampling and reconstruction theorem.

Comment: Instead of copying the answer, you should flag this question as a duplicate of the one where this answer was posted.

Comment: It's not exactly the same answer, @MarkRansom.  Nor the same question.  And this answer is not complete.  It's just that I didn't feel like completing it at 1 am.