Multitudinous definitions of "linear"
I ran into this question in a mixed signal design class where the textbook keeps referring to sampling systems as being non-linear, as though by default, but I still do not see what part of the definition of a linear system, the sampler automatically doesn't meet.
Yes, it isn't linear as in it isn't some operator taking input x and outputting f(x) = mx + b  from 7th grade math.  But what part of the linear system definition does it automatically not meet? I'm hoping someone else can explain this better.   By the way, I'm an old man like probably most of you guys, not a college kid.  I still have aspirations of knowing what I'm doing one day, though, so I'm still taking continuing studies courses.)
My question:

I don't see why sampling, in Maloberti eq 1.1 has to be a non-linear system, based on the definition of a linear system.  The sampler system takes in a signal and puts out a different one.  I don't see anything in that yet saying the system does a different operation based on input amplitude (a x(t) ), which would make it non-linear, or that it wouldn't output H{a x1(t)} + H{b x2(t)} when there are multiple scaled input signals.

Professor responds:

Sampling replaces a continuous-in-time signal with a series of values that are spaced in time by the sampling interval (inverse of sampling rate). What happens to all of the now-unseen values between the samples? We have lost all direct information about them, and we can easily end up with frequency folding (aliasing), in which multiple frequency components of our original signal now overlap one another. See also Baker's Chapter 1, which many students prefer over Maloberti's initial chapters.

My reply:

So the system is considered non-linear because you cannot recover the original signal by the applying the inverse of the impulse response of the system to the output?
From the normal definition of a linear system, I don't understand where that condition is.


Your prof is wrong, at least if they knew they were saying sampling is nonlinear.  Without including enough of a relevant quote from your textbook, or pointing to an online copy of the relevant section, we can't tell you if the textbook is wrong.

Linear and time-invariant are not the same thing.  Most often we discuss LTI systems that are both linear and time-invariant.  The curious thing is that uniform sampling (which we'll call "$\mathbf{T}{\cdot}$") appears to be linear in that if $y_1(t)=\mathbf{T}{x_1(t)}$ and $y_2(t)=\mathbf{T}{x_2(t)}$, then it is true that $y_1(t)+y_2(t)=\mathbf{T}{x_1(t)+x_2(t)}$.  But the sampling operation generates frequency components that didn't exist in the input. These would be the images. I guess that is due to the time-invariance.  So my guess is that uniform sampling is linear.

@TimWescott is right, sampling is time-variant, but still linear as a mathematical ideal. Furthering that point, sampling can be viewed as an orthobasis expansion. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/94055/why-is-sampling-not-idempotent/94056#94056

It would be helpful if you could add a scan of the equation including the text around it.

Nice question!!

@robertbristow-johnson: non-uniform sampling is still linear -- it still obeys superposition.  It's just a lot messier than uniform sampling.

I agree, Tim.  It's just that with uniform sampling, I know where I'm gonna see the images appear.  I can grok it and do math with it.  Much harder with non-uniform sampling.

Looks like I need to change my notification settings or pay attention more.   ----Thanks.  That's what I thought.  Time invariant--meaning the system will do the same thing regardless of when you approach it.  Same thing at night, same thing on a hot day, same thing despite having been heated up and given a ton of input---time invariant.          I tried to put the equation in, then tried to put a screenshot in, but I'm not familiar with how the site takes them yet.

A popular and (in its place) useful definition of sampling:
$$x[n] = x(n T_\mathrm{s})\ n \in \mathbb Z \tag 1$$ where $T_\mathrm{s}$ is the constant sampling interval.
A nicely mathematically rigorous and (in its place) useful definition of sampling:
$$x_\mathrm{s}(t) = \sum_n \delta(t-n T_\mathrm{s}) x(t) \tag 2$$
Note that these can be tied together:
$$x_\mathrm{s}(t) = \sum_n \delta(t-n T_\mathrm{s}) x[n] \tag 3 $$
Each one of these obeys superposition.  Because each one of these obeys superposition, each one is linear.
Sampling is a linear process.
Your prof has succumbed to a popular confusion about system linearity vs. system time variance.
When viewed in the time domain ((2) is best for this), sampling is a time varying process.  It is this time varying quality that causes aliasing.

Note that, first, nonlinear systems also generate signal components at frequencies that are not in the original signal [although creating new frequencies doesn't automatically make a system non-linear].  This helps to confuse people about the distinction between time-varying and nonlinear systems.
Note that, second, if you want to build a physical system that samples a signal (i.e., you want to implement (1) with a sampler or an ADC), then that physical example of a mathematical ideal will necessarily contain nonlinear components.  This also confuses people.
However, just because a physical system contains nonlinear components, this does not mean that it cannot be modeled in a perfectly satisfactory manner as a linear system.

Please let us know how your professor reacts went you present him with these hard cold facts!

Dang, beat me to the punchline haha! Nice answer.

(+1) and just because a system generates other frequencies, it doesn't mean that it is non-linear (a time domain "mixer" is another example where time variance is confused with non-linearity-- with the mixer we move one frequency to another but the operation is linear. It is even more confusing that mixers can be implemented with non-linear diodes but in the double balanced mixer, those diodes are intended to be ideal switches, and for that frequency translation operation the design it is completely linear, while the spurs are do the the secondary non-linearity!)

It's Dan Boschen...great.  Just kidding, hey Dan.

I actually got a student answer after what I posted, which also didn't make sense.  I asked again what condition of "linear system" sampling didn't meet, and didn't get an answer.  But the train of that that class is way off down the track now, without me on it, so there won't be a reply from the professor probably.  But I think that in engineering practice, usage of the term "non-linear" has degenerated into a qualitative judgement-based adjective used to generally mean "strange" or "not the output we want."

This is good stuff Tim and Dan.  Amps are always "weakly nonlinear."  There are always harmonics regardless of whether we're in the "linear region," AND, those harmonics don't grow at the same rate with input signal amplitude (so, it fails condition 1 for a linear system).  But the "linear region" for an amp means the function relating input to output is a line; not that it's ever a linear system.  My understanding was always that a system could do as weird of a thing as it wanted to an input and still be linear, as long as it did the same thing regardless of input power or input signal type.

@Blue42: your definition of linear isn't, really -- a system is linear if it obeys superposition.  The mathematical test for that is to feed the sum of two signals through the system -- if the result is always the sum of the system's individual responses to the individual signals, no matter what the signals, then the system is linear.

Kudos for such a good question and insight.
Sampling is a linear operation.  Aliasing is a nonlinear artifact, but it arises not because sampling is nonlinear, but because of insufficient sampling—specifically, violating the Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem.
Sure, there can be loss of information, but that has nothing to do with aliasing, as your professor seems to suggest, or with the linearity of the sampling operation.

Thanks. But what do you mean by aliasing being "a nonlinear artifact?"  That would seem to say that if you have aliasing, the system that produced it had to be non-linear.
