# How best analyze a very short data record (~100 data points) windowing and padding data to perform CWT

Tags: window, cwt

I have short segments of a biological signal interpolated at 10 Hz (anywhre from about 8.5 sec to 10 sec length). I want to use a cwt to then convert this segment to frequency over the short time frame. I believe need to window the time function and remove the average to make the average value zero, and then pad with zeroes to obtain 128 data points. The frequency range I am interested in would be above about 0.3 Hz to .45 Hz

My question relates to the time domain signal --- windowing, remove the zero frequency and padding the data and in what order, prior to using the CWT.   Thank you very much.  I am working in MATLAB

Comment: you have *samples*, i.e. *discrete time*; why do you want to use the *continuous* wavelet transform? In fact, if you want to go to frequency domain, why *wavelets* at all – the transform that links time domain and frequency domain is the Fourier transform.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sorry, this comment is nonsense.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon how so?

Comment: This topic has been covered extensively on DSP.SE, mainly by me, a little by others. Two posts focus exclusively on it. As consistent with history, it appears you've been intentionally ignoring my writing. Ignorance is a fair choice, but not going around suggesting to others they're doing something wrong, especially if they're newbies, when you have no idea what you're talking about. This isn't the first time. @MarcusMüller

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon you have a meta post where you say conflict in a post could have been avoided. Yet you're very aggressive to me here; I'm not sure what to make of it. I'm not ignoring your writing. You claim what I say makes no sense, I ask you why, and I get attacked. That's not good faith behaviour, sorry.

Comment: I do have a meta post, and it does [mention you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liEMN.png), and how you ignore my writing. As for this case - [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/76624/50076) you raise a similar sentiment, and I provide a very explicit answer. Recently there was an explicit question on naming itself, which I also [answered](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/86713/50076). Given your activity on DSP.SE, it strikes me as very unlikely you simply "didn't get chance to read". Sure, it's possible, but not in Case 1, unless you can explain? @MarcusMüller

Comment: Thanks, that March 7 answer of yours seems to be actually about this – and pretty extensive. I'll have to read it. I was in actual ignorance of that, but not out of choice – I simply cannot possibly read all posts on here! It's a lot. (I find it strange that you *complain* about a comment being upvoted and not disputed. What's the problem with that? People have no duty to contradict me if I contradict you, or vice versa. This doesn't mean anybody attacks you unfairly. I have been wrong in public, and I'm fairly certain you've been, too. Human nature and such.)